# реализация iteratora

Tags: java

Здравствуйте,есть задача

```
private class IteratorImpl implements Iterator<Object> {
   public boolean hasNext() { 
         //returns true if the iteration has more elements // ... 
   }  
   public Object next() {  
        // returns the next    element    in the iteration // ... 
   } 

   public void remove() {
       //removes from the  underlying collection the last element  returned by this iterator //    ... 
   }
}
```

Алгоритм в методе remove может быть следующим:

> ЕСЛИ ПЕРЕД ВЫЗОВОМ remove НЕ БЫЛ ВЫЗВАН МЕТОД next ИЛИ ПЕРЕД ВЫЗОВОМ
>   remove БЫЛ ВЫЗВАН remove (повторный вызов remove) ТО ВЫБРОСИТЬ
>   ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЕ (так и вставить в код):   throw new
>   IllegalStateException();
>   В ДАННОМ МЕСТЕ ОПРЕДЕЛИТЬ И УДАЛИТЬ СООТВЕТСТВУЮЩИЙ ЭЛЕМЕНТ

первые два метода реализовал,остался remove.

**Вопрос:** вот его я и не пойму как реализовывать? Как узнать какие методы были вызваны до remove и как удалять тоже не пойму.

Comment: Можно булеву сделать, в вызове next делать ее тру, а в вызове remove - false. В remove проверять, если она false кидать исключение(в начале метода!!!)

Comment: Спасибо большое,после Вашего коммента мозги включились и всё сделал.